# How to display associated JSON data together in a backbone.js .eco template

Tags: json, backbone.js, coffeescript, eco

So here is my JSON data;

```
    {
        "team_name": "New Team!",
        "user_name": "hey_user",
        "games": []
    },
    {
        "team_name": "New Team!",
        "user_name": "testing_user",
        "games": []
    },
    {
        "team_name": "Another Cool Team!",
        "user_name": "test_user_2",
        "games": []
    }
```

I'm adding this to my .eco template:

```
 <% for person in @persons: %>
    <%= person.team_name %>    
    <%= person.user_name %> <br /> <br />
 <% end %>
```

Which outputs this:

```
New Team! hey_user
New Team! testing_user
```

But I want it to output:

```
  New Team! hey_user, testing_user, etc.
```

So the Team Name doesn't keep appearing for each new user, if that makes sense. Best way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Brandon I've tried various approaches, but they either don't work (i get an error) or they don't seem possible for what I want. I've toyed around with indexing, but I can't wrap my head around it. Thanks.

Comment: It will help other users to show what you've tried, but it seems like you'd want to format the objects before sending them to the template to eliminate the duplication rather than putting a lot of complex logic in your templating.

Comment: @brandon yeah maybe there isn't a good way to do this in the template...my approaches are embarrassingly bad. I'll keep plugin away at it. But, I'm thinking it might have to be addressed in my APIs or in my models or both...

Comment: It's ok to be embarrassingly bad :) That's just part of learning. Your templating should always be as dumb as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to group users by teams. You can use underscore's [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) method

```
var groups = _.groupBy(json, 'team');
```

It will give you something like that:

```
{
    "New Team!": [
        {
            "team_name": "New Team!",
            "user_name": "hey_user",
            "games": []
        },
        {
            "team_name": "New Team!",
            "user_name": "testing_user",
            "games": []
        }
    ],
    "Another Cool Team!": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Then you can pass this to template, iterate over it and print team and then iterate through inner array of users. If you need array instead of hash, you can run [pairs](http://underscorejs.org/#pairs) over it.